# VBA Macro. Assign to Array when if statement is used and display in message box

Tags: excel, vba

Dim NumberOfErrors As Integer

```
    NumberOfErrors = 0

    If Dir(FilePath) = "" Then ' This is declared earlier and working ok

    NumberOfErrors = NumberOfErrors +1

    Dim ErrorArray() As Integer
    ReDim ErrorArray(NumberOfErrors)

    ErrorArray = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value

    End If
Next cell

If NumberOfErrors > 0 Then

       MsgBox "Attachments Do Not Exist for The Following Users: " & ErrorArray(NumberOfErrors)

End If
```

So just to try and clarify what i am trying to do. If the file does not exist then create a dynamic array to show the names of the non existent files. Pass them to an array and show a list in a message box of the files that did not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array isn't dynamic since you always size it to 4, but you should move the Dim line out of the loop, and then use:

```
ReDim Preserve ErrorArray(NumberOfErrors)

ErrorArray(NumberOfErrors) = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
```

or you could also use a Collection or Dictionary rather than an array.

In order to use the array with `MsgBox` you'll need to use `Join`:

```
MsgBox Join(ErrorArray, vbLf)
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rory but still no luck. When i follow your advice there is no errors but still now there's no message box at all. I'm very new to this and trying to figure it out.
If you could give some advice on how to use either collections or dictionaries arrays i could give it a go. As long as i get a list of all the errors displaying at once rather than numerous messages then i am happy! At the moment i can only get one item in each box!

Comment: I've just corrected a typo where I wrote `ErroryArray` rather than `ErrorArray`. Your `NumberOfErrors = 0` line should not be inside the loop in the real code - is it?